# Can I create Slack subscriptions to an AWS SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack

I'm trying to create a SNS topic in AWS and subscribe a lambda function to it that will send notifications to Slack apps/users.

I did read this article -
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-lambda-webhooks-chime-slack-teams/

that describes how to do it using this lambda code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import urllib3
import json
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxx"
    msg = {
        "channel": "#CHANNEL_NAME",
        "username": "WEBHOOK_USERNAME",
        "text": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'],
        "icon_emoji": ""
    }
    
    encoded_msg = json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')
    resp = http.request('POST',url, body=encoded_msg)
    print({
        "message": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'], 
        "status_code": resp.status, 
        "response": resp.data
    })
```

but the problem is, that in that implementation I have to create a lambda function for every user.

I want to subscribe multiple Slack apps/users to one SNS topic.
Is there a way of doing that without creating a lambda function for each one?

Comment: How can the Lambda function identify the Slack user that should receive the message?

Comment: That's part of what I'm asking.... the same way that a topic sends it's subscriptions to lambda, there might probably be way to send it slack users and extract there id or something

Comment: But does the message itself contain a User identifier, so you know who should be messaged in Slack? Or are you wanting to send it to _all_ Slack users?

Comment: Yes the message should include the identifier

Comment: Then can you extract the User identifier from the message and use that to send the message to the appropriate Slack user?

Answer (score 5):

You really DON'T need Lambda. Just SNS and SLACK are enough.

I found a way to integrate AWS SNS with slack **WITHOUT** `AWS Lambda` or `AWS chatbot`. With this approach you can confirm the subscription easily.

Follow the video which show all the step clearly.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CszzQcPAqNM

Steps to follow:

- Create slack channel or use existing channel
- Create a work flow with  selecting Webhook
- Create a variable name as "SubscribeURL". The name
  is very important
- Add the above variable in the message body of the
  workflow Publish the workflow and get the url
- Add the above Url as subscription of the SNS You will see the subscription URL in the
  slack channel
- Follow the URl and complete the subscription
- Come back to the work flow and change the "SubscribeURL" variable to "Message"
- The publish the
  message in SNS. you will see the message in the slack channel.

Comment: That did the job! The workflow UI has changed a bit since the video was created, but the steps are quite similar, it should not be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would say you should go for a for loop and make a list of all the users. Either manually state them in the lambda or get them with api call from slack e.g. this one here: https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import urllib3
import json
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    userlist = ["name1", "name2"]
    for user in userlist:
        url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxx"
        msg = {
            "channel": "#" + user, # not sure if the hash has to be here
            "username": "WEBHOOK_USERNAME",
            "text": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'],
            "icon_emoji": ""
        }
        
        encoded_msg = json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')
        resp = http.request('POST',url, body=encoded_msg)
        print({
            "message": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'], 
            "status_code": resp.status, 
            "response": resp.data
        })
```

Another solution you can do is set up email for the slack users, see link:
https://slack.com/help/articles/206819278-Send-emails-to-Slack
When you can just add the emails as subscribers to the sns topic. You can fileter the msg that the receiver gets with Subscription filter policy.

Comment: Thanks for the response,
can this be implemented as a topic subscription?

Comment: I don't know if i fully understand your question but emails can be subscribers to a SNS topic. So by giving the slack channel/user a email pointing to their channel you can use that as a subscriber. So in that case you don't need a lambda.